# Connecting PHP with Oracle MacOS

Tags: php, oracle, macos

I am new to Oracle and PHP. I tried to connect to it multiple times but I am still struggling.

I write the Php Files on TextEdit for MacOS and upload them to the FileManager of a Hosting Service like Dreamhost or Bluehost. I access the DB via the internet at Oracle Database Actions / SQL.

I saw `$ora = oci_connect('system', '1234Abcd', '//192.168.178.43/orcl.shared');` in the article below and now that system is the db_username and 1234Abcd the db_password but I don't now the rest of the code.

https://marc.vos.net/howto/oracle-oci8/

And my hosting service confused me even more by saying the items of oci_connect must also include the username and password of the hosting service.

Please help me out! :)

For further details just leave a comment.

Comment: So you want to connect from your Mac over the internet directly to a an oracle database that is already running on a host of a provider? That is a bit unusual but technically possible. Since you not your prover have sufficient oracle knowledge, why not register for an always free subscription at https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/ That would make your life setting it all up a lot easier.

Comment: What would be the common way in my case? @ik_zelf

Comment: That depends on how much time you want to spend and with what goal. If one of the goals is learn to install and maintain a database: fire up a Linux vm and create one there. Lots of helping docs online. Otherwise I would go for the oracle always free tier. It gives you a provider who seriously knows about oracle databases.

Comment: @ik_zelf alright, will do. Could you explain the part after the db_password?

Comment: Another advantage of going with free oci is the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/developer-tutorials/tutorials/apache-on-oracle-linux/01-summary.htm I hope this helps.

Comment: Your hosting provider will need to make the OCI8 extension and Oracle Instant Client libraries available. You will need to work out how to use Oracle's 'wallet' files to get a secure network connection to the Oracle DB (the current exception is if you use the re-cut 19.13 Instant Client on Linux 64 since this supports walletless "1-way TLS"). You will need to know a database username and password. You may find it easier to start with Python and follow https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/python/quickstartpython.html  Once you have this working then you can look at PHP

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to subscribe to the oracle alway free oci tier. https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/
This gives you a good, free working database and a platform to develop on. It also gives you a wealth of documentation that help you step by step to get the bits connected.
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/developer-tutorials/tutorials/apache-on-oracle-linux/01-summary.htm

If your goal is to learn to install and maintain oracle databases start with creating a vm to install oracle on. When the application part and the db part are both new, start walking, start with free oci (Not saying this is slow btw) learn how it works and if you still want, install php on your Mac. It certainly is possible but OS X has its quirks.